# Query With Multi-Level Nested Arrays Using Linq

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a model such as:

```
{
  nestedArray1: [
    {
      nestedArray2: [
        {
          id: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to get the items which contain nestedArray2 with the id value that is among the list `x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]`.

I tried to run the following query with no avail:

```
var query = model.AsQueryable().Where(m => m.nestedArray1.Any(s => s.nestedArray2.Any(m => ids.Any(id => id == m.id))));
var results = query.ToListAsync();
```

It says that any filter is unsupported.

What is the proper way of writing such a query using Linq?

**NOTE:**

Here is how I can do it using Mongo query syntax:

```
db.getCollection('model').find({
    "nestedArray1": {
        $elemMatch:{
            nestedArray2:{
                $elemMatch:{
                  "id" : {$in: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

})

And here is how I can do it using C# without Linq query syntax:

```
var ids = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var filter = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Model>()
        .ElemMatch(p => p.nestedArray1, new FilterDefinitionBuilder<NestedModel1>()
            .ElemMatch(s => s.nestedArray2, new FilterDefinitionBuilder<NestedModel2>()
                .In(m=> m.id, ids)));
return await Collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: `Any()` returns a `bool`. You want to filter, so to me it is unclear what your desired output is. Could you give an example?

Comment: @iSpain17 Editted the original post to include the full query syntax.

Comment: I think we are gonna need the FindAsync<T> definition if Tim's answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your model the items of nestedArray2 only have a field with one ID.

So considering your example above, you should have something like this (i think):

```cs
var query = model.AsQueryable().Where(m => m.nestedArray1.Any(s => s.nestedArray2.Any(m => ids.Contains(m.id))));
```